# Which countries are registered as companies in the USA?

Tags: united-states, australia, securities-and-exchange-commission

I know that [Australia is registered as a company in the USA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commonwealth_of_Australia_(US_Corporation)).

What more countries are registered there?

If none, why did Australia feel the need to register themselves as a company?

Comment: Note very well: That's wikipedia for ya. The title of the linked wikipedia page is "Commonwealth of Australia (US Corporation)". The article body contradicts the title and says "Form 18-K registrations are used only for foreign government registrations with the SEC and **do not create a corporation**."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are many countries, states/provinces, and organizations that are registered with the [SEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S._Securities_and_Exchange_Commission) and have filed an 18-K [form](https://www.sec.gov/files/form18-k.pdf), and they file it so they can issue [securities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_(finance)) in US markets.

[This site](https://sec.report/) tracks SEC filings, and you can look up 18-K filings [here](https://sec.report/Document/Header/?formType=18-K&page=1) (and any other bureaucratic forms you're interested in). The data seems to go back to 2002 and there are 792 entries, though there are many duplicates from groups re-registering or amending their registration. I'm not sure if it's a complete list, since the site isn't associated with the SEC and just aggregates data from the SEC's [EDGAR system](https://www.sec.gov/edgar/about).

There are too many entities to list here, but here are a few countries' filings I saw while skimming through the pages:

- [Australia](https://sec.report/Document/0001341004-10-001680/), as you noted (last filed in 2010)
- [Canada](https://sec.report/Document/0001193125-21-363455/) (2021)
- [Italy](https://sec.report/Document/0001341004-21-000315/) (2021)
- [Jamaica](https://sec.report/Document/0001193125-21-303690/) (2021)
- [Sweden](https://sec.report/Document/0001104659-13-075445/) (2013)
- [Mexico](https://sec.report/Document/0001193125-22-170073/) (2022)

There are also several foreign organizations in that list, such as the [Asian Infrastructure Investment Bank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asian_Infrastructure_Investment_Bank) (last [filed](https://sec.report/Document/0001193125-22-092012/) in 2022) and the [Council of Europe Development Bank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Council_of_Europe_Development_Bank)  (last [filed](https://sec.report/Document/0001104659-22-044977/) in 2022), as well as some states/provinces such as [Ontario](https://sec.report/Document/0001193125-21-363027/) in Canada (2021) and [Queensland](https://sec.report/Document/0001193125-22-009232/) in Australia (2021).